# How to find number of records based on association through join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have `User`, `Assignment`, and `Account` models. Users can belong to many accounts and accounts have many assignments. As an admin on an account you can 'assign' users to an assignment. I'm trying to find how many users are assigned to a particular assignment. Also, users and assignments have a join table called `assignment_relationships`. That table has a boolean that flips if the user is assigned to that table – the attribute is called `designated`. This is kinda confusing but it should be pretty straight forward. Here are the associations:

User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :account_memberships
  has_many :accounts, through: :account_memberships
  has_many :assignment_relationships
  has_many :assignments, through: :assignment_relationships
end
```

Account:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments
end
```

Assignment:

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord    
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :assignment_relationships
  has_many :users, through: :assignment_relationships
end
```

Assignment_relationships:

```
class AssignmentRelationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :assignment
end
```

So as a recap, I'm trying to find a query that will tell me how many users are assigned to a particular assignment. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like perhaps I'm missing something in your question (because my answer is incredibly simple) but why can't you just do:

```
@assignment.users.count
```

Since it appears that you have your `has_many, through:` relationship set up properly, calling `users` on an `Assignment` object should correctly go through your `assignment_relationships` join table to return any users connected to the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(users.id), assignments.id
FROM assignment_relationships
WHERE designated IS TRUE
GROUP BY assignments.id
```

You just need one table ideally